# Christmas came three days early to felons

Tags: word-usage, time-reference

Which is correct? "Christmas came three days **early** to felons" or "Christmas came three days **earlier** to felons"?

> The wave of corrupt presidential pardons began Wednesday.
>
> **Christmas came three days early to felons** George Papadopoulos, former Congressmen Duncan Hunter and Chris Collins, and 17 others.
>
> Hunter and Collins lined their family's pockets by misusing campaign
> funds or inside information. Papadopoulos lied to the FBI in the
> Mueller investigation.
>
> Source: [The Hill](https://thehill.com/opinion/judiciary/531453-trumps-corrupt-pardons-expose-another-gap-in-us-legal-system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Early vs Earlier](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109220/early-vs-earlier). See also [“Early” vs “earlier” this morning / this month](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72553/early-vs-earlier-this-morning-this-month) and [Early and earlier](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/168362/early-and-earlier).  Syntactically, both forms are "valid" in your context, but ***early*** is by far the most idiomatically established version.

Comment: ...See [this usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Christmas+came+early+that+year%2CChristmas+came+earlier+that+year&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CChristmas%20came%20early%20that%20year%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally "Early".  As an adverb it means "before the usual or expected time"

> I'll finish work early today.

The metaphor here is that people usually receive gifts on the 25th.  But these criminals had the gift of freedom given to them on the 22nd, in the form of a Presidential pardon.